# Simple non-blocking infinite loop using asyncio

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a non-blocking while loop but my code is blocking ("Next!" does not get printed). I appreciate any help or hint. Thank you.

```
import asyncio

class TaskManager:

    def __init__(self):
        self.start_loop()

    @asyncio.coroutine
    def running_loop(self) -> None:
        while True:
            # do something async!

            yield from asyncio.sleep(1)

    def start_loop(self):
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        loop.run_until_complete(self.running_loop())
        print("Next!")

TaskManager()
```

Comment: The code after running loop won't execute until loop finishes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`run_until_complete()` will do just that, it will wait for the coroutine to complete before moving on,you have to call the function one step at a time for it to be an actual coroutine but if you dont have a main loop to call `running_loop` from then you might as well just use `threading`